# Método correto para exibir/esconder interface de acordo com perfis/regras/credenciais com Angular 2+

Tags: html5, angular, componentes

Estou precisando, para o sistema atual que desenvolvo, uma forma de esconder ou exibir componentes de acordo com os perfis, por exemplo:

Perfil: **Master**

> Exibir Botão de Visualizar, Criar, Editar e Remover Cadastros

Perfil: **Controles Internos**

> Exibir apenas o botão de Visualizar Cadastros

Para este caso,  o que eu pensei foi o seguinte: Criar um componente verificador, que pede o perfil e a permissão exigida para a visualização de seu conteúdo, como exibo no código abaixo:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RuleCheckService } from 'src/app/core/services/rule-check/rule-check.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rule-check',
    template: `
    <ng-template [ngIf]="canShowContent">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
    `,
    styleUrls: []
})
export class RuleCheckComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    public ruleGroup: string; // Grupo de regras ao qual o perfil deve se encaixar
    @Input()
    public permissionCheck: any; // Permissão necessária para exibição do conteúdo, podendo ser string ou array de string

    public canShowContent = false; // Verifica se deve ou não exibir o conteúdo do componente, de acordo com as regras verificadas

    constructor(
        private ruleCheckService: RuleCheckService // Serviço que puxa o usuário logado, obtendo suas permissões
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.checkPermission();
    }

    checkPermission() { // Método que fará a verificação e alterará para visível ou não
        if ( this.ruleGroup === null || this.permissionCheck === null ) {
            this.canShowContent = false;
            return;
        }

        const $check = this.ruleCheckService.check( this.ruleGroup, this.permissionCheck )
        $check.subscribe( permission => {
            this.canShowContent = permission;
        });
    }
}
```

Tem alguma forma mais prática e/ou mais inteligente de utilizar esta situação?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, com o **pipe async**.

Em vez de fazer a assinatura no observável, já insira ele diretamente no HTML.

**No HTML:**

```
<ng-template *ngIf="check$ | async">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

**No TS:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.check$ = this.ruleCheckService.check(this.ruleGroup, this.permissionCheck).pipe(take(1));
}
```

A condição *!this.ruleGroup || !this.permissionCheck* deve ser inserida dentro do service.

Eu inseri o *$* no final porque é o padrão para variáveis *Observables*.
O *asyncPipe* é o valor do observável toda vez que ele sofre alguma mudança, sem a necessidade de fazer um *subscribe*.

Outra observação: Utilizar HTML em arquivos HTML e ng-template quando diver uma segunda condição no HTML. Exemplo:

```
<div *ngIf="check$ | async; else outraCoisa"> Uma coisa </div>
<ng-template #outraCoisa>
            Outra coisa
</ng-template>
```

Neste exemplo, o ng-template se torna um *else* e a *div* principal um *if*.